# adding search button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I parsed the data into table format using jquery but i want to create a search boxes for specialty and rating how to create using jquery can some one help me regarding this thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var doctorsData = '[{"Name":"John","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Max","speciality":"dentist","area":"fremont","rating":"10" },        {"Name":"Suzi","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"fremont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Ron","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"8" },{"Name":"Tracy","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Terry","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"fremont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Steve","speciality":"dentist","area":"Belmont","rating":"10" },{"Name":"Lee","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"Belmont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Luci","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"Belmont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Lema","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"Belmont","rating":"6" },{"Name":"Stan","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"Belmont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Sam","speciality":"dentist","area":"Belmont","rating":"5" }]';

        var table='<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Speciality</th><th>Area</th><th>Rating</th></thead><tbody>';
        var obj = $.parseJSON(doctorsData);
        $.each(obj, function(){
           table =table+ '<tr><td>'+this['Name']+'</td><td>'+ this['speciality']+'</td><td>'+this['area']+'</td><td>'+this['rating']+'</td></tr>';
        });
        table = table+'</tbody></table>';
        document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML=table;
    });
```

```css
 .search{
            margin-bottom: 10px;

        }
        table,th,td{
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
    Speciality:<input type="text">
    Rating<input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="datalist"></div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. Check out [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It's a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you want (and more).

Answer (score 0):

I've outlined a method below for your Speciality box. You should be able to learn enough from it to try the Rating box on your own.

---

First, you'll want to add ID's to your input boxes so that we can pick them up easily with jQuery.

```
Speciality: <input type="text" id="txtSpeciality">
Rating: <input type="text" id="txtRating">
```

Next, add a listener so that we can check for matches every time someone types in the input box:

```
$("#txtSpeciality").on("input", function() { //When someone types in the box
     var spec = $(this).val(); //Get the value from the textbox
     var $hasText = $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(2):contains(" + spec + ")"); //Find any cells in column 2 that have the value from the textbox
     $("table tbody tr").hide(); //Hide all rows
     $hasText.parent().show(); //Show any that have the text
});
```

And the final product looks something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var doctorsData = '[{"Name":"John","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Max","speciality":"dentist","area":"fremont","rating":"10" },        {"Name":"Suzi","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"fremont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Ron","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"8" },{"Name":"Tracy","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Terry","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"fremont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Steve","speciality":"dentist","area":"Belmont","rating":"10" },{"Name":"Lee","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"Belmont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Luci","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"Belmont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Lema","speciality":"cardiologist","area":"Belmont","rating":"6" },{"Name":"Stan","speciality":"orthopaedic","area":"Belmont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Sam","speciality":"dentist","area":"Belmont","rating":"5" }]';

        var table='<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Speciality</th><th>Area</th><th>Rating</th></thead><tbody>';
        var obj = $.parseJSON(doctorsData);
        $.each(obj, function(){
           table =table+ '<tr><td>'+this['Name']+'</td><td>'+ this['speciality']+'</td><td>'+this['area']+'</td><td>'+this['rating']+'</td></tr>';
        });
        table = table+'</tbody></table>';
        document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML=table;
  
        $("#txtSpeciality").on("input", function() {
             var spec = $(this).val();
             var $hasText = $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(2):contains(" + spec + ")");
             $("table tbody tr").hide();
             $hasText.parent().show();
       });
    });
```

```css
.search{
            margin-bottom: 10px;

        }
        table,th,td{
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
    Speciality:<input type="text" id="txtSpeciality">
    Rating<input type="text" id="txtRating">
    </div>
    <div id="datalist"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a typo throughout: I think you're looking for "specialty".

You'll want to add a class to each of the search inputs so you can identify them later:

```
<div class="search">
    Specialty: <input class="specialty" data-col="specialty" type="search" />
    Rating: <input class="rating" data-col="rating" type="search" />
</div>
```

Then change around your JavaScript so that you can rebuild the table with a filtered set of data, and add an event to each of the inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var doctorsData = [{"Name":"John","specialty":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Max","specialty":"dentist","area":"fremont","rating":"10" },        {"Name":"Suzi","specialty":"cardiologist","area":"fremont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Ron","specialty":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"8" },{"Name":"Tracy","specialty":"orthopaedic","area":"fremont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Terry","specialty":"cardiologist","area":"fremont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Steve","specialty":"dentist","area":"Belmont","rating":"10" },{"Name":"Lee","specialty":"cardiologist","area":"Belmont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Luci","specialty":"orthopaedic","area":"Belmont","rating":"7" },{"Name":"Lema","specialty":"cardiologist","area":"Belmont","rating":"6" },{"Name":"Stan","specialty":"orthopaedic","area":"Belmont","rating":"9" },{"Name":"Sam","specialty":"dentist","area":"Belmont","rating":"5" }];
    // Render with all the data once the DOM is ready
    renderTable(doctorsData);
    // Add an event that fires whenever a search term is changed
    // (this can optionally be changed to fire whenever a key is pressed)
    $('.search input[type="search"]').on('change', function(){
        var $input = $(this);
        var searchCol = $input.data('col');
        var searchText = $input.val();
        renderTable(getFilteredData(doctorsData, searchCol, searchText));
    });
});

function getFilteredData (originalData, colName, text) {
    var data = [];
    text = text.toLowerCase(); // optional
    if (text.length == 0) { // if there is no search term, use all data
        return originalData;
    }
    // Loop over original data...
    $.each(originalData, function(i, row) {
        // If we find the search text then add this row to the data to return
        if (row[colName].indexOf(text) > -1) {
            data.push(row);
        }
    });
    return data;
}

function renderTable (data) {
    var table = '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Speciality</th><th>Area</th><th>Rating</th></thead><tbody>';
    $.each(data, function(){
       table += '<tr><td>' + this['Name'] + '</td><td>' + this['speciality'] + '</td><td>' + this['area'] + '</td><td>' + this['rating'] + '</td></tr>';
    });
    table += '</tbody></table>';
    document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML = table;
});
```

Comment: "Speciality" is the British English equivalent of "specialty".

Comment: @Santi - Sorry for the American-English-centric edit to that!

Comment: I'm not OP, I submitted an answer as well and thought the same thing so I double-checked haha.